# How to properly call a PHP function?

Tags: javascript, php, html, function

I currently have a PHP function which I need to call from a different file to populate a Javascript variable. I can populate the Javascript variable just fine. However when calling the PHP function I get an error message stating that

> Use of undefined constant getEstGrid - assumed 'getEstGrid' in
>   phpcom/db/estimatesCom.php</b> on line 29.

Here is my include file which has the function:

```
<?php include 'phpcom/db/estimatesCom.php';?>
```

Here is where I'm calling the function:

```
<?php echo getEstGrid($resultsE); ?>
```

Function code:

```
function getEstGrid($resultsE){//<--This is the variable passed to the function
  if ($resultsE->num_rows > 0) { //<--- Check to see if the variable is greater than zero
    $rows = array(); //<--- Create an empty array calls "rows"
        while ($r = $resultsE->fetch_assoc()){//<--- While the database records are being returned create a variable called "r" and assign DB record.
           $rows[] = $r; //<-- assign each DB record row to the array.
        }
        $data = array('Estimates' => $rows);//<--- Create a variable an assing the array to it.
  }
  //header("Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8");
  echo json_encode($data, true);//<--- Endode the "data" variable to a JSON format.
  return getEstGrid;//<--- Return the created fucntion.
}
```

If anyone can help with this I would really appreciate it.

Comment: what does the function definition look like?

Comment: Looks like you don't have a function called `getEastGrid()`.

Comment: So what's on line #29 in estimatesCom.php?

Comment: No pleas look at the question there is no getEastGrid(); However there is "getEstGrid()".

Comment: On line 29 is "return getEstGrid"

Comment: I think you need to include the code in estimatesCom.php to your question.

Comment: are you using any arrays in the included file???

Comment: Yes I am. Take a look at the function code I just added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change this:

```
echo json_encode($data, true);//<--- Endode the "data" variable to a JSON format.
return getEstGrid;//<--- Return the created fucntion.
```

By this:

```
return json_encode($data, true);
```

This way, the function just returns the data, and you can choose whether echo it o do any other thing with it out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this return statement from your function:

```
return getEstGrid;//<--- Return the created fucntion.
```

Why have you used that? Not needed.

Also, if you are using `echo` in your function you don't need to use `echo` while calling your function to print the output.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to return the function in order to use it in another file.

Instead, just return the value you need from the function:
return json_encode(...

When you try to return "getEstGrid", php is looking for a constant with that name, which doesnt exist.

Comment: using this <?php echo getEstGrid($resultsE); ?> worked after fixing the function to return json_encode($data, true);